# octobercms - how to open admin login page

Tags: admin, octobercms

October CMS is totally new for new. My previous guy has not shared the URL to hit logon to the admin panel of a website which is developed in October CMS.

I googled a lot, but not getting any link. Kindly let know me this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The default url is `/backend`
But this can be changed in the config file.

Comment: Hi Dragontree, 
Thank you for your response, I tried website url/backend but it redirects me to home page. I tried clearing cookies but no luck.
Any other option i need to try....

Comment: Do you have access to the source files?